# Mysql cluster strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, replication, cluster, mysql-cluster

I have 2 mysql clusters on two different servers with management node on each of them.

It went down someway.

I ran following commands to start the cluster:

Start the management node on srv1:
srv1: mysqlc/bin/ndb_mgmd --initial -f my_cluster/conf/config.ini --configdir=/home/mysql_cluster/my_cluster/conf

Start the management node on srv2:
srv2: mysqlc/bin/ndb_mgmd --initial -f my_cluster/conf/config.ini --configdir=/home/mysql_cluster/my_cluster/conf

Start the ndbd nodes on srv1:
srv1: mysqlc/bin/ndbd --initial -c localhost:1186

Start the ndbd nodes on srv2:
srv2: mysqlc/bin/ndbd --initial -c localhost:1186

Start mysqld server on srv1:
srv1: mysqlc/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=my_cluster/conf/my.cnf --user=root &

and here is the problem.
mysql server not loading the data. Only database names are present. All the tables which are ENGINE=ndbcluster are not being loaded. Tables with ENGINE=myisam are being loaded.
Backup scripts helped me load the data.

But this way I can't use cluster setup.

Similar issue appeared when i started srv2.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you make everytime an "initial" this means that the cluster starts with a clean filesystem. You can read it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster-start-phases.html)